# How to design a relational DB to capture the same entity as reported by multiple sources?

Tags: database-design

I need a DB that can capture instruments as reported by a bank and two accounting firms. Let's take Walmart stock as an example. The bank may have a instrument named "Wal-Mart Stock". One of the accounting firms may have it named as "Walmart Stock". The other accounting firm may have "Wal-mart common stock".

Here's the diagram that I have so far:

[image: ER]

* Table contains five additional columns. These five column names are the same for `MasterInstrument` and `DataSourceInstrment`.

The `DataSource` represents the bank, accounting firms, or any other entity that can provide data.

The `DataSourceInstrument` represents the instrument data as provided by the `DataSource`.

`MasterInstrument` is a version of the instrument specific to the application itself. So, in our example, it may contain "Walmart Common Stock" for the instrument name. It's different than `DataSourceInstrument` b/c unlike `DataSourceInstrument`, it is used extensively throughout the application and it must maintain a history of changes.

The `Instrument` table provides a way to know that several different data sources are referring to the same instrument. `DataSourceInstrument` and `MasterInstrument` with the same `instrumentId` are referring to the same instrument. (`Instrument.id` is a surrogate key b/c some instruments do not have a natural key, and the `DataSourceInstrument`s and a `MasterInstrument` may need to be manually mapped as referring to the same instrument.) So, using the Walmart example, we can know that the bank, two accounting firms and the internal system are referring to the same Walmart instrument.

The `Issuer` represents the issuer of the instrument such as "Wal-Mart Stores, Inc." Note: It only needs to be captured for `MasterInstrument`s.

I have a couple of doubts on this design:

1. Is it poor design to have a table (i.e. `Instrument`) with only a single surrogate column? If this is a problem, how would it be designed differently?
2. Are the various *Instrument table names confusing? If so, how could it be more clear?

Overall how should the design account for the need to capture multiple sources referring to the same instrument along with the need to capture an internal version of that instrument with history?

**Update**

The system's primary function / raison d'être is reporting. It must report for a given date what the internal instrument (i.e. `MasterInstrument`) data was on that date. This is why I have `MasterInstrument` as a history /temporal table and do not have the columns in `Instrument`.

Comment: Not sure why you *need* `instrument_id`. Wouldn't a `DataSourceInstrument` be linked to one and only one `MasterInstrument`? If so, no reason why `DataSourceInstrument` shouldn't use `masterintrument_id` as a direct foreign key to `MasterInstrument`.

Comment: No because `MasterInstrument` is a history table. So many rows in `MasterInstrument` can refer to the same `Instrument`. I forgot to note in the OP that the system's primary function is reporting. It must report on a given date what the internal instrument (i.e. `MasterInstrument`) data  was on that date.

Comment: There, the naming convention gets odd. `MasterInstrument` Implies the records represent the basic, "unchangeable" values for the instrument. What you call `Instrument` I might have called `MasterInstrument` (and moved "unchangeable" values there), and what you call `MasterInstrument` might be `InstrumentHistory` (however, a deeper understanding might change that).

Answer (score 1):

> Is it poor design to have a table (i.e. Instrument) with only a single surrogate column? If this is a problem, how would it be designed differently?

If that is the only constant property of the entity then that is fine, but I would assume that there are other invariant properties such as a name ("Walmart" in your example). Even if the same "instrument" can be referred to by different names by each source and issuer (those names then belong in the relation table) do they not have a canonical name?

> Are the various *Instrument table names confusing? If so, how could it be more clear?

It depends a lot on how well you document them and/or the names and naming conventions in your target industry.

Table names should be as descriptive as possible (you can always shorten them in queries using aliases) avoiding generic words where possible. Where a generic name is needed because nothing more speciifc isn't too specific then I would suggest the simplest generic word that fits (item, object, thing) rather than instrument, but that is personal preference.

For junction tables (relation tables, or whatever you call them as there are several common names for the same concept) I recommend the name represents the row entity types in the relationship - so IssuerInstrument rather than MasterInstrument in your diagram.

Comment: Thanks. Instrument refers to a [Financial Instrument](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Financial_instrument). Some instrument attributes (such as symbols) probably could be considered invariant but the data sources are not constrained to provide the same value and I'm not sure what the business value is to capture what might be considered invariant data.

Comment: In regards to a junction table, I see the asymmetry in the `MasterInstrument` table name. It does have a different relationship / purpose than `DataSourceInstrument` though.   An issuer may issue many different instruments. However, I can't join directly to the `Instrument` table (and put the`MasterInstrument` cols there) b/c I need to maintain a history for reporting and that's the primary purpose of the system. Please see my update in OP. Sorry I left that out originally. Note: The system does not need to capture the issuer for `DataSourceInstrument` .